# Returning data from PHP response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My AJAX request is this -

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/feed-check.php",
        dataType: "json",       
        data: {
            server: server,
        },  
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.Agencies').html('<p>'+data[0]+'</p>');
        }           
    })
```

The above returns and array like this below

```
[{"feed_name":"example.zip","feed_time":"2015-10-16 00:00:24","feed_size":"1222","back_office"
:"example4","agencyID":"example2"},{"feed_name":"example2.zip","feed_time":"2015-10-16 08:20:00","feed_size"
:"3145","back_office":"example1","agencyID":"aaa"}]
    "
```

How do i get the data out when the complete function is done in the AJAX request I am trying to do it like this

```
        complete: function(data) {
            $('.Agencies').html('<p>'+data[0]+'</p>');
        }
```

But i am getting undefined, can someone tell me where i am going wrong? I need to get all of the data out.

My PHP script -

```
        $whereArray = array(
            "$where",
            "=",
            $_POST['server'],
        );

        $andArray = array(); //- Blank 'AND' array so that the 'get' call below doesn't fail if no 'ANDs' are passed.
        $orArray = array(); //- Blank 'OR' array so that the 'get' call below doesn't fail if no 'ORs' are passed.
        $order = array();

        $agencyfeed = paddyDB::getInstance("paddy_ms")->get('feed_files', $whereArray, $andArray, $orArray, $order);

        //print_r ($agencyfeed->results());
        $feeds = [];
        foreach ($agencyfeed->results() as $key) {

            $feeds[] = $key;
            //$key = $feeds['feed_name'];

        }

        echo json_encode($feeds);
```

### Was looking at the wrong file, derp. Have updated the post with the relevant details

Thank you.

Comment: did you specify the dataType?if not you need to parse the result so you can get the data like that example after you parse `data['feed_name']`

Comment: i have specified the data as - dataType: "json"

Comment: you can loop through data and get the value you want using `for loop` or `$.each`

Comment: its better to show the `console.log(data);` instead of the `print_r`

Comment: @Pekka my console.log(data); returns an Object, i can't post this.

Comment: Please change your response to json object from ajax/feed-check.php  with json_encode php function. Then you can parse json object in ajax response.

Comment: are you `json_encode` the response from php? you should get a something not an object on `console.log`

Comment: @SashantPardeshi I am already using echo json_encode($response), which gives the Array above.

Comment: @Pekka, you would get an Object, but you should still be able to see the content of it. http://jsfiddle.net/813zvb1m/

Comment: @Pekka sorry i misunderstood, it returns the same array as above.

Comment: @Styphon what i mean is he wont get [Object object]

Comment: @Kieron606 yes show it instead of print because that is what you are working on not the `print_r`

Comment: @Pekka I am showing the `console.log` now

Comment: that is the exact console.log?that is not a correct json if you have a success and error in your ajax you will always go to error. Like i asked earlier did you do `json_encode` in your php?

Comment: @Kieron606 you should be getting similar to `{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}` in your console.log

Comment: can you change you ajax like this `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/feed-check.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        server: server,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.Agencies').html('<p>' + data[0] + '</p>');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Not Correct JSON");
    }
})` and run it

Comment: @Pekka I changed my AJAX request to that and i do get the alert.

Comment: @Kieron606 now you know what your prob is. fix the json reponse from php and your code will work

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Sorry, @Pekka I have been looking at the wrong PHP file. I have updated the post now.

Comment: @Kieron606 check this it will help http://jsfiddle.net/wgvqkjs0/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
complete: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, member) 
                {
                    $(".Agencies").html('<p>'+data[i].feed_name+'</p>');
                })

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you told your ajax request to expect a JSON response? If not then it doesn't decode the JSON and you just end up with a string. Use console.log(data) to check, you'll probably get a string.

You can get jQuery to automatically convert the JSON into an object by setting `dataType: "JSON"` in the [jQuery.ajax options](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I have done this and i get an Object as the console response.

Comment: And what do you get if you do `console.log(data[0])`?

Comment: OK, so when you do `console.log(data)` and it shows the object, there should be a black arrow next to it that you can click and view the contents of the object, what is in it?

Comment: I have changed the post to show the contents of the Object

Comment: Sorry, Styphon I have been looking at the wrong PHP file. I have updated the post now.

Comment: I parse the repsonse $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: @RichardTestani I get this error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: It sounds like maybe your json is invalid. Paste your json response here: http://jsonlint.com and see if it checks out. I've had issues with proper quoting and such.

Comment: @RichardTestani JSONlint tells me its valid

Answer (score 1):

Please try code below.
I have used $.each function nested to parse your json object. 
Please refer jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sashant9/npq9efur/2/

** Please let me know, If your desired output is different.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/feed-check.php",
        dataType: "json",       
        data: {
            server: server,
        },  
        complete: function(data) {
            $.each(data , function(index, value){
                  $.each(value, function(ind,val){
                        $('.Agencies').append('<p>'+val+'</p>');    
                  });
           });
        }           
    });
```

Output -->

example.zip

2015-10-16 00:00:24

1222

example4

example2

example2.zip

2015-10-16 08:20:00

3145

example1

aaa

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I've found a solution now

```
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(k,v){
            var serverCont =  '<tr>';
                serverCont += '<td>'+v.feed_name+'</td>';
                serverCont += '<td>'+v.feed_date+'</td>';
                serverCont += '<td>'+v.feed_time+'</td>';
                serverCont += '<td>'+v.feed_size+'kb</td>';
                serverCont += '<td>'+v.agencyID+'</td>';
                serverCont += '</tr>';      
                thisServer.append(serverCont);                      
            });
        },
```